# Can I use std::move more than once when assigning to different base classes?

Tags: c++

```
HashTable & operator= (HashTable && rhs)
{
    destroyElements();
    free();

    std::swap(buf, rhs.buf);
    std::swap(m_size, rhs.m_size);
    std::swap(grower, rhs.grower);

    Hash::operator=(std::move(rhs));
    Allocator::operator=(std::move(rhs));
    Cell::State::operator=(std::move(rhs));
    ZeroValueStorage<Cell::need_zero_value_storage, Cell>::operator=(std::move(rhs));

    return *this;
}
```

Does `rhs` become invalid after the call to `Hash::operator=`?

Comment: Please don't do that

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - What, reuse code?

Comment: It might be preferable to have `[[no_unique_address]]` members instead of bases. Aside: do you really need to ensure that `rhs` ends up empty?

Comment: @StoryTeller std::move the same object multiple times.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - Good thing the OP doesn't do that

Comment: @StoryTeller none of those functions might change the state of rhs, but it is brittle coding.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - No it isn't. It doesn't touch the same object twice, even if they are all nestled inside `rhs` as sub-objects. Stop spreading FUD please.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am not spreading anything. There is no way you know what any of those functions do from this sample. It is very possible that `Hash::operator=` takes in an argument of type `HashTable &&` and modifies data in a way to interfere with the other calls. Do prove me wrong using _just the code OP provided_.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - You can say that about *any* function (and you are so moving the goal post in bad faith here). FUD is exactly what's in your "warning". Nobody said pathological code doesn't exist, but reasonable people write code based on expected pre-conditions of the components they use.

Comment: It's not malicious if some developer 5 years down the road decides to add an overload for some purpose; no one expects you to `std::move` the same object multiple times. `std::move` is meant to request a move of the object. If you want to move a part of the object, you should be more explicit instead of abusing the semantics.

Comment: Great, another goal post shift. Done here.

Comment: I don't think warning about misuse of `std::move` three times with varying degrees of detail shifts anything. You're welcome to think otherwise. I don't go about accusing people.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - "misuse" is in the eye of the beholder. If you want to think up pathologies to create "best practices" over, go for it. I'll call out such BS whenever I see it, whether you feel "accused" or not.

Comment: I've explained my case with a complete example. Readers can decide what is BS.

Comment: The general principle for standard library objects is that once the object is moved from it is left in a *valid but unspecified* state.  Suitable for destruction, or re-assignment.  Methods with no preconditions are okay to use.  Some objects have additional guarantees (like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector`).  Your **own** types can have whatever post-move state your code guarantees; I tend to follow the *valid but unspecified* rule for my own types so I don't have to remember which-is-which.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming neither of those bases does something obscene like mess with the state of the other bases, then it should be fine.

```
Hash::operator=(std::move(rhs));
```

The cast to an rvalue produces a `HashTable&&` here. That in turn can be implicitly bound to a `Hash&&` (assuming an accessible and unambiguous base). So the operator only operates on the `Hash` sub-object. And you do not access *that* object again, following the guideline of not using an object after it has been moved from.

Same goes for the other bases.

All in all, if your classes are well-behaved and maintain their own invariants correctly during move assignment. this is a viable way to implement the move. Heck, even a defaulted move operation *delegates* to the move operations of bases.

Comment: `std::move<Hash>(rhs))` etc might be more explicit about what is going on

Comment: @Caleth - Could be, nice stylistic choice I must say.

Comment: @Caleth Does that actually work? The parameter would be a rvalue reference. It should be `std::move<Hash&>(rhs)`, no?

Comment: @Caleth - That might actually be a no-go in retrospect. If `std::move` accepts by forwarding reference, then specifying the type will hard-code the parameter is an rvalue reference, and so we'd need a `std::move(rhs)` anyway.

Comment: Ironically... `std::forward<Hash>(rhs)` *will* work, but I dunno if it reads the same.